# how to achieve model-specific type inference from prisma model without explicitly passing the index string to PrismaClient object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, backend, prisma, repository-pattern

Context: I'm using prisma ORM with typescript. I'm applying a repository pattern abstraction such that I have an interface **'IRepository'**, and an impure abstract class **'BaseRepository'** which implements this interface to take care of basic CRUD operations (so that I don't have to re-write the implementation of these operations). Model Repositories can simply extend the base repository to get access to these basic CRUD functions.

code examples:

```js
export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseDTO> implements IRepository<T> {
    public prisma = new PrismaClient();

    async read(options?: ReadQueryOptions | undefined): Promise<T[]> {
        // prisma query
    }

    async create(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
        
    }

    async update(options: Partial<T>, data: Partial<T>): Promise<T[]> {
        
    }
    
    delete(options?: QueryOptions | undefined): Promise<T[]> {
        
    }
}
```

a class **'UserRepository'** can simply extend it:

```js
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository
```

**The Problem**
Since I'm making an abstract class, It can't relate to a specific model which extends it. thus, indexing the prismaClient becomes a problem.:

```
export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseDTO, U extends keyof PrismaClient> implements IRepository<T> {
    // doesn't work, no type inference:
    const modelName: U
    this.prisma[modelName]

   // using string also doesn't work:
   const modelName: string
   this.prisma[string]
{
```

As you can see, I've tried:

- using string
- using keyof PrismaClient

How can I achieve the type inference and code completion in this abstract class?